# Lines of txt read as NoneType

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, nonetype

I am using python3 to open a text file in the current directory and read through all of the lines.

Each line in `test.txt` is a path to an image.

My objective is to get the path before the file extension (which works), but then when I try to use the `path` object to concatenate with a different string, python doesn't recognize `path` as a string object even after I try converting with `str()`.  Rather, it sees it as NoneType.  What am I doing wrong here and what is the workaround?

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as ins:
    lines = ins.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        path = print(line.split('.')[0])
        print(type(path))
```

**Output:**

```
/Users/admin/myfolder/IMG_1889
<class 'NoneType'>
```

---

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as ins:
    lines = ins.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        path = print(line.split('.')[0])
        print(str(path))
```

**Output:**

```
/Users/admin/myfolder/IMG_1889
None
```

this is what's in the file:

```
$ cat test.txt
/Users/admin/myfolder/IMG_1901.jpg
/Users/admin/myfolder/IMG_1928.jpg
/Users/admin/myfolder/IMG_2831.jpg
/Users/admin/myfolder/IMG_1889.jpg
/Users/admin/myfolder/IMG_2749.jpg
/Users/admin/myfolder/IMG_1877.jpg
```

Comment: Can you show us how `test.txt` looks like

Comment: Change `path = print(line.split('.')[0])` to `path = line.split('.')[0]`

Comment: `path = print(line.split('.')[0])`?

Comment: You don't need `readlines`; `for line in ins:` is more efficient.

Comment: If you believe your question has been answered, please accept one of the answers. Otherwise, please edit your question or leave a comment so that we can answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the line

```
path = print(line.split('.')[0])
```

you assign the return result of `print` (which is `None`).

you might want to use:

```
path = line.split('.')[0]
print(path)
```

and there is no need for the `lines = ins.readlines()` line.

all in all i suggest you use

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as ins:
    for line in ins:
        path = line.split('.')[0]
        print(path)
        print(type(path))
```

Answer (score 4):

The `print()` function returns `None`. You need to assign `path` to the result of the split, then print that.

```py
with open("test.txt", "r") as ins:
    lines = ins.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        path = line.split('.')[0]
        print(path)
        print(type(path))
```

You should, however, be using the standard library for this task (version 3.4+):

```py
import pathlib

with open('test.txt', 'r') as ins:
    for path in (pathlib.Path(line) for line in ins):
        print(path.stem)
        print(type(path.stem))
```

Your current solution would fail to extract the part of the filename before the extension if the filename has more than 1 `.` in it, which is fairly common. Using pathlib avoids this issue, and provides many more useful features.

Comment: i like this `pathlib` approach!

Answer (score -2):

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as ins:
    for line in ins:
      if line is not None:
        path = line.split('.')[0]
        print(type(path))
```

Comment: How does the guidance in this answer differ from the guidance in the previous answers already posted?